# Node reports syntax error from ellipsis when using TypeScript variable args

Tags: asynchronous, typescript, promise, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to write a helper method for converting node's `fs` methods to TypeScript's async methods (leveraging ES6 generator functions), and having some trouble with the ellipsis I use for variables args:

```
function makeAsync<T>(method: (...args: any[]) => void, ...args: any[]) : Promise<T> {
    return new Promise<T>((resolve, reject) => {
        args.push((err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
        method.apply(null, args);
    });
}

export async function readdirAsync(path: string) {
    return makeAsync<string[]>(fs.readdir, path);
}
```

This compiles fine by tsc, but at runtime node complains about the generated .js file containing the ellipsis:

```
function makeAsync(method, ...args) {
                           ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: try to put `...args` in square brackets like `[...args]`

Comment: `async function`s are not an ES6 feature. They're not even in ES7.

Comment: When I do that, the caller is forced to pass the parameters as an array instead of individual parameters. Still, I could live with that. But I guess at that point the ellipsis isn't buying me anything.

Comment: Quite right, @Bergi. It's a TypeScript feature that is only enabled when compiling to ES6.

Comment: What version of Node are you using? Per [node.green](http://node.green), rest parameters weren't supported without a flag before 6.0.0.

Comment: 4.4.5. Thanks, @Bakkot

Comment: @AndrewArnott then you need TypeScript to target ES5 and not ES6 or run the resulting code through Babel. I think only the latter is a real option since TypeScript doesn't do async functions for an ES5 target until 2.0